# Grouped barplot and percentages on bars

Tags: r

suppose to have the following data.frame

> ```
> Age group       Hospital_A         Hospital_B         Hospital_C
>    0_17            12.69               3.6                9.5
>    18_24            2.23               4.5                6.6
>    25_30            22.3              12.4               10.2
> ```

Is there a way to generate a barplot where on x-axis age-groups should be represented while on y-axis percentages and bars should be Hospitals* grouped by age groups? Something like this: [image] where instead of Team, I need age groups and bars should be hospitals. Is there also a way to add percentages (rounded numbers) on top of bars? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the `R` code you have tried so far? It helps others if you make a minimal reproducible example as outlined in the `R` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably like this bar graph.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
library(ggthemes)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-Age_group,
               names_prefix = "Hospital_",
               names_to = "Hospital") |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=Age_group, y=value, fill=Hospital)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label=value, y=value+1),
            position=position_dodge(width=.9)) +
  theme_few() +
  scale_fill_d3()+
  labs(x="Age group", y="Percentage(%)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with **rAmCharts4**:

```r
resp1 <- c(67, 58, 42, 47, 43, 48)
resp2 <- c(33, 42, 58, 53, 57, 52)
question <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
dat <- data.frame(question, resp1, resp2)

library(rAmCharts4)

amBarChart(
  data = dat,
  category = "question",
  values = c("resp1", "resp2"),
  valueNames = c("Response 1", "Response 2"),
  chartTitle = "My grouped bar chart",
  theme = "kelly",
  valueFormatter = "#p",
  tooltip =
    "[bold font-style:italic]{valueY.value.formatNumber('#p')}[/]"
)
```

[image]